# 50,000+ Questions and counting... thats awesome

Tags: discussion

Just noticed our community has gone past **50,000+** questions... its great to see how this community is growing and how we help each other...

Thanks to all the moderators and all the community members who keeps this an awesome place for us to visit everyday and learn something new..

```
< everyone is awesome here />
```

Comment: Is there a way to work out what percentage of questions are answered and accepted, and compare that to the other stackexchange communities?

Comment: You might be able to write a query to pull that information on https://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/queries

Answer (score 4):

This number is indeed awesome. As someone who enjoys these questions immensely, I want to thank everyone who takes the time to post their own here.

In response to the comments asking about accept percentage, it is pretty easy to use search to figure out how many questions there are (`is:question`) and how many are accepted (`isaccepted:yes`). Here's how we stack up (ha) against some other communities.

```
Community                     Questions    Accepted Answers    Accepted %
Stack Overflow               12,705,877           6,928,325         54.5%
English Language & Usage         76,653              40,410         52.7%
Code Review                      38,883              22,936         67.7%
Salesforce                       50,489              22,337         44.2%
Science Fiction & Fantasy        34,959              21,279         60.9%
WorldBuilding                     8,601               4,933         57.4%
```

Comment: So we do need to increase the number of accepted answers really. One problem I find is when I have to do an 'No that can't be done answer' it often does not get accepted probably because the OP is not pleased by the answer for all that it is true.

Comment: Yes, our number is quite low. And those answers do contribute to the problem, but I think that's not the majority case.

Comment: Yes, having a look at questions with unaccepted answers it seems like a big issue is the number of drive by posters that seem to give up when they don't get an immediate answer or have changed their credentials.